# Ajax фильтрация для json массива в интернет магазине

Tags: php, json, ajax

Нужна помощь с формированием фильтров в интернет магазине на Wordpress c, написанным на php, каталогом, карточки товаров которого подтягиваются через API запрос с CRM заказчика.

Вводные.

1. Через API запрос и json_encode формирую массив из которого формирую карточки товаров в каталог.
2. Нужно над каталогом сделать фильтры, в формате тегов , которые будут без перезагрузки страницы фильтровать массив.

Как понимаю нужно использовать Ajax. Но на просторах сети не нашел примеров. Можете посоветовать куда копать? Может есть какие-то статьи материалы?
По соображениям пунктов о неразглашении, не могу массив предоставить.

Если кто-то сталкивался, если есть примеры, поделитесь, пожалуйста!

Спасибо!

Comment: ``По соображениям пунктов о неразглашении, не могу массив предоставить.`` интересно, и чего же вы ожидаете?))

Comment: Если честно, совет, что почитать, что посмотреть, в какую сторону копать